# Query Orchard CMS from IShapeFactoryEvents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am trying to insert shapes into my layout from my module once it has been enabled. I figured IShapeFactoryEvents would be perfect for this, but querying the CMS from here gives me a "TransactionScope nested incorrectly exception" if this occurs during a POST. Wondering if anyone had any words of wisdom for me again? See my code snippet below.

```
    public void Created(ShapeCreatedContext context)
    {
        if (context.ShapeType == "Layout")
        {                
            if (!AdminFilter.IsApplied(_services.WorkContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext))
            {
                var route = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(_services.WorkContext.HttpContext);
                object location;
                if (route.Values.TryGetValue("location", out location))
                {
                    var region = _services.ContentManager.Query("Region")
                        .Join<RoutePartRecord>()
                        .Where(x => x.Slug == (string)location)
                        .Slice(1).FirstOrDefault();

                    context.Shape.Header.Add(context.New.CurrentRegion(Title: region.As<RoutePart>().Title), "10");
                }
                context.Shape.Navigation.Add(context.New.RegionSelector(Regions: _services.ContentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Published, "Region").List()), "11");
            }
        }
    }
```

Once again, thanks in advance. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the blog post I did on this very topic here: http://chrisbower.com/2011/02/15/orchard-shape-wizardry/

From the blog post:

> "One thing I need to note, and this took me an entire day to discover, is that you can't just inject your data service into your IShapeTableProvider implementation. If you do, it'll try to use a transaction out of scope and that will cause you all kinds of problems. After tearing my hair out for hours on end, I finally discovered what the Orchard team is doing inside of the CoreShapes class: The trick to resolve a service dependency within the function itself by using a property that loads the service per-request."

Try using your service like this instead:

```
private IOrchardServices Services     
{
    get
    {
        return _workContextAccessor.GetContext(_httpContextAccessor.Current()).Resolve<IOrchardServices>();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @chris-bower, worked a treat. How is your site progressing? Is it in production yet?

Comment: @Chris The other solution would be to inject `Work<T>` instead of `T` to `IShapeTableProvider` implementation ctor. You can then access the underlying object via `Value` property of `Work<T>`. It returns an instance appropriate for the current context. Useful thing when you need to inject per-request dependencies into singleton dependencies.

Comment: @pszmyd - Nice. Was this something added to 1.2? I must have missed that.

Comment: will I have similar problems querying the cms from say a scheduled task handler? @Chris I have actually checked your blog out in the past and your site. Looks pretty good, Orchard proving itself well? I am trying to sell it for my organisations public web site (www.nib.com.au) but not sure if I will get there.

Comment: @Brendan - The scheduled tasks run inside of a transaction (all of them under the same in 1.2). You can query the DB just fine. However, any updates (under 1.2) will be rolled back if any other scheduled tasks blow up. But yes, Orchard is working well for us. I'm going to try to write a case study in the near future.

Comment: @Chris One of the hidden features of 1.1:)

Comment: @PiotrSzmyd Please you please elaborate on the `Work<T>` class. Where is it defined? I can't find any documentation.